# Find Stationary Point(s) for function (two variables): $f(x,y)=3y^3-x^3-2y^2+4x-2y$

Tags: derivatives, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative, stationary-point

> Find all stationary pointsfor function
> $$f(x,y)=3y^3-x^3-2y^2+4x-2y.$$

So far this is what I have
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(3y^3-x^3-2y^2+4x-2y\right)=-3x^2-4$$  and
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(3y^3-x^3-2y^2+4x-2y\right)=9y^2-4y-2$$

What do I do from here? I know it's somthing along the lines of making them equal to $0$.

Comment: In the first, it is $ +4$ instead of $ -4$.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(3y^3-x^3-2y^2+4x-2y\right)=-3x^2-4$

but it should read

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(3y^3-x^3-2y^2+4x-2y\right)=-3x^2+4.$

If $x_0$ is such that  $-3x_0^2+4=0$ and if $y_0$ is such that  $9y_0^2-4y_0-2=0$,

then $(x_0,y_0)$ is a  stationary point of $f.$